# background-image: url(); not working

Tags: html, css, url, background, background-image

I'm trying to get an image as a background in this section but it's not working. There is no problem with the link inside the url();
I am only working with HTML and CSS.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<section>

  <div>
    <h3>Verliefd</h3>
    <h4>En ik dacht aan jou...</h4>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="verliefd.html">
      Lees verder
    </a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
main > section:first-of-type {
height: 15em;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(/Images/Schermafbeelding%202018-08-27%20om%2019.56.38.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: never use space when you name your image files, never! or you will suffer ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the url:

```
background-image: url('/Images/Schermafbeelding%202018-08-27%20om%2019.56.38.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(asset-path("Schermafbeelding%202018-08-27%20om%2019.56.38.png"));
```

or

```
background-image: url("Schermafbeelding%202018-08-27%20om%2019.56.38.png");
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. What worked for me was putting the full path of the image from my pc, instead of from just inside the project folder.

i.e.

```
background-image: url('C:/Users/Username/FolderName/Images/Schermafbeelding%202018-08-27%20om%2019.56.38.png')
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32914066)